# Cannot use 3rd party libraries in git hooks

Tags: python, git, githooks

I have implemented a pre-commit git hook in python which uses [javalang](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang).

I have installed javalang using `pip install javalang` on my machine. However, when I commit something and my pre-commit script hook executes - I get an import error when the script attempts to import javalang.

Why am I getting this error? I have already checked in my terminal that I can use javalang so why can't the script see it?

UPDATE:

My shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env python`

When I type `which python` I get `/usr/local/bin/python`

The full error is: `ImportError: No module named javalang`

Output when I do a `echo $PATH` in my terminal: `/usr/local/bin:“/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:“/Users/<my_name>/Applications/apache-ant-1.9.6”/bin/"`

Comment: Got it. Can you also paste he `pre-commit` script with the full error log? Also please tell us what the [she bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for the `pre-commit` hook file is?

Comment: If you type `which python` in the terminal, is that the same Python you're using in the first line of your `pre-commit` hook?

Comment: You've had two requests to post what the first line in the script is. Suppose its `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and you `pip install javalang` which installs into python 2. That would be a problem. These guys are trying to lend a hand with your problem so throw them a crumb!

Comment: I updated my question, sorry for the delay I was busy.

Comment: Can you also update your answer with what you get when you `echo $PATH` in your terminal?

Comment: @kiran.koduru done